# Impressive swelling capacity of grain when being cooked

Tags: verbs, adjectives, phrases

How to describe a grain-food i.e. rice having impressive capacity to swell when being cooked. Especially when it has more capacity when compared with others (varities) of its' kind on same measure before being cooked.

**EDIT**: I am hoping there could be a shorter and stylish or more common way used by English native speakers to express such situation. As in my local language. I researched on reverse dictionary at.www.onelook.com, it gave me some words i.e. expansive, expansible, multiplicative, versatile, etc. but I am not satisfied. That is why I asked here for better help.

Comment: Do you want a scientific term?  An advertising term?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo. Yes I want it.

Comment: This rice is more **absorbent** than other rice.   This rice **plumps up** more than other rice. This rice **gets plumper** than other rice.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo **absorbent** and **plumps up** are good, but the term **plump** is used in the industry to refer to the aspect ratio of the uncooked grains: short grain rice is plumper than long grain rice. https://wholegrainscouncil.org/whole-grains-101/easy-ways-enjoy-whole-grains/grain-month-calendar/wild-rice-september-grain-month-0

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/73937/does-brown-rice-or-white-rice-expand-more-when-cooked

Comment: ["Embiggen"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/embiggen) is a perfectly [cromulent](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cromulent) word for this situation.  *"Our rice **embiggens** more than other varieties of rice"*  (Note:  these are not real words.  They are made-up words from the popular American television satire "The Simpsons".  It's even funnier that they actually appear in the Oxford Living Dictionary.)

Answer (score 2):

"This rice doubles in volume when cooked." Based on e.b.white's writing in "The Elements of Style", this sentence is prefered because it is concise, clear, and direct. Just so you know, I do not know if any variety of rice actually doubles in volume when cooked.  That was used just for purposes of illustration.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.

Comment: Nathan, my post has been updated.  Thank you. Gary

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you want.

How about "fluffy"? So you could say something like, "Brand X rice cooks up fluffier than Brand Z's rice" or "Grain A is 10% fluffier than Grain B."

I've seen fluffy used to describe less-dense breads, scrambled eggs, and other foods as well as rice, quinoa, and other grains.